# Identify bear periods in a time series, stock data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, stock

How do one identify (bear)periods in a time series where price decrease is larger than a certain threshold, within a certain amount of time and the data time is not periodic?

For instance, identified (bear)periods should decrease in price with 3 percentage or more within 2 hours.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random

def random_times(stime, etime, n):
    frmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    stime = datetime.strptime(stime, frmt)
    etime = datetime.strptime(etime, frmt)
    td = etime - stime
    return [random.random() * td + stime for _ in range(n)]

# Getting historical, daily ohlc data from yfinance
msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
hist = msft.history(period="max")

# Generating random datetimes for rows in yfinance data
datetimes = random_times('2020-01-01 00:00:00','2021-01-30 00:00:00',len(hist.index))
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(datetimes)
datetimes = datetimes.sort_values()

# Dataframe with random datetimes and real MSTF close prices
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'time': datetimes,
                    'close': hist['Close']})
df = df.set_index('time')

df.plot(figsize=(50,30))
```

[image]

Comment: [Stock Data Analysis with Python](https://ntguardian.wordpress.com/2018/07/17/stock-data-analysis-python-v2/) might help you. There's a section on detecting Bearish trends.

Comment: Thank you @TrentonMcKinney! Reading the article from your link I found information on how to detect bear periods based on moving averages only, not taking the degree of price decline nor time restraint into consideration. There was alot of other useful information though, so again, thank you very much :)